# How to mix one audio driver with the GUI of a prior version?

Tags: audio, drivers

I have a Gigabyte [Z87MX-D3H](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z87MX-D3H-rev-1x) that comes with Realtek® ALC892 codec. Gigabyte provides drivers for it, but they stopped on 2016-02-23. Realtek provides much newer drivers, always updated. I'm running Windows 10.

There is no strict need to update drivers continuously, but these are over 18 months old and I would like to try a refresh.

The drivers from Gigabyte provide a control panel sitting on the Taskbar that allows me to choose each plug's behaviour. For example, my front connector for headphones is broken and I assigned the front "microphone" jack as headphones output instead.

The official drivers don't provide this function. They show in the Control panel (audio card section) the various jacks, but no way to assign them to specific functions.

Can (and how) I mix the newer bare drivers with the older control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to why you would want to change a running system with no need to do so, but anyways:

Gigabyte might have their drivers configured to the features of the motherboard while the stand-alone drivers are built for the chip alone. Therefore, the chip itself does not know that your motherboard provides the possibility to reroute the jack configuration. It might not be a bad idea to stay with the old drivers as they provide the functionality you want and otherwise don't cause any other problems. Old drivers aren't automatically bad.